# Replace items in JComboBox with array

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I was wondering if there was an easy way to do this. I'm trying to remove the items from the weapons combobox (with success), and then add the array into the combo box like how it was when it was first instantiated. I don't want to just create and copy a new one, because there are body constraints already set to the liking. Here is the code...

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

public class TestGui extends JFrame {
    private final String[] guiCharSelDefault = {"---  Select Character ---"};
    private final String[] characters = {"charOne", "charTwo", "charThree", "charFour"};
    private final String[] GuiCharSel = (String[]) ArrayUtils.addAll(guiCharSelDefault, characters);
    private final String[] weapon = {"Weapon"};
    private final String[][] allWeapons = {
            {
                    "weakWeaponOne", "strongWeaponOne", "shortWeaponOne", "longWeaponOne"
            },
            {
                    "weakWeaponTwo", "strongWeaponTwo", "shortWeaponTwo", "longWeaponTwo"
            },
            {
                    "weakWeaponThree", "strongWeaponThree", "shortWeaponThree", "longWeaponThree"
            },
            {
                    "weakWeaponFour", "strongWeaponFour", "shortWeaponFour", "longWeaponFour"
            }
    };
    private JComboBox charCombo = new JComboBox(GuiCharSel);
    private JComboBox weaponsCombo = new JComboBox(weapon);
    private JPanel centerFrame = createCenterFrame();

    //**************************************************************************************

    private GridBagConstraints setGbc(int gridx, int gridy, int ipadx, int ipady, String anchorLocation, double weightx, double weighty, Insets insets){
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        if (anchorLocation.toUpperCase().equals("NORTHWEST")){
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
        } else if (anchorLocation.toUpperCase().equals("NORTH")){
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
        } else if (anchorLocation.toUpperCase().equals("NORTHEAST")){
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHEAST;
        } else if (anchorLocation.toUpperCase().equals("WEST")){
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        } else if (anchorLocation.toUpperCase().equals("EAST")){
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
        } else if (anchorLocation.toUpperCase().equals("SOUTHWEST")){
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.SOUTHWEST;
        } else if (anchorLocation.toUpperCase().equals("SOUTH")){
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.SOUTH;
        } else if (anchorLocation.toUpperCase().equals("SOUTHEAST")){
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.SOUTHEAST;
        } else {
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        }

        gbc.gridx = gridx;
        gbc.gridy = gridy;
        gbc.ipadx = ipadx;
        gbc.ipady = ipady;
        gbc.weightx = weightx;
        gbc.weighty = weighty;
        gbc.insets = insets;

        return gbc;
    }

    private Insets setInsets(int top, int left, int bottom, int right){
        Insets insets = new Insets(top,left,bottom,right);
        return insets;
    }

    //**************************************************************************************

    private JPanel createCenterFrame(){
        JPanel pnl = new JPanel();
        Border raisedBevel = BorderFactory.createRaisedBevelBorder();
        Border loweredBevel = BorderFactory.createLoweredBevelBorder();
        Border compound = BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(raisedBevel, loweredBevel);

        pnl.setBorder(compound);

        charCombo.addActionListener(
                new ActionListener() {
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        String charName = ((JComboBox)(e.getSource())).getSelectedItem().toString();
                        if (charName.equals("charOne")){
                            weaponsCombo.removeAllItems();
                            weaponsCombo.addItem(allWeapons[1]); // <---- Help Please!!!
                        }
                    }
                }
        );
        pnl.add(charCombo, setGbc(0,0, 0, 0, "NORTHWEST", 0, 0, setInsets(0, 10, 0, 0)));
        pnl.add(weaponsCombo, setGbc(0,0, 0, 0, "NORTHWEST", 0, 0, setInsets(0, 10, 0, 0)));

        return pnl;
    }

    TestGui(){
        add(centerFrame, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        setSize(800,600);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    //**************************************************************************************

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestGui();
    }
}
```

Line 95 (`// <---- Help Please!!!`) is where I'm wondering if there is an easy way to do this. The problem is when you select "charOne" in the character combobox on the gui, you see a weird language string instead of a list of the 4 weapons in the weapon combobox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple solution is simply to replace the `ComboBoxModel`...

```
if (charName.equals("charOne")) {
    DefaultComboBoxModel<String> model = new DefaultComboBoxModel<>(allWeapons[1]);
    weaponsCombo.setModel(model);
}
```

See [How to Use Combo Boxes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) for more details

Comment: This seemed to work as well so I could still use `JComboBox` > `weaponsCombo.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(allWeapons[1]));`. Thanks :)